# why is this piece wrong in jupyter-notebook while it's correct in terminal?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch

When I ran this piece of code in jupyter, it didn't run correctly. The error is :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
last) <ipython-input-16-76d9b57527d4> in <module>
     14 embed_layer = emb()
     15 
---> 16 inp = torch.tensor([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ])
     17 
     18 out = embed_layer( inp )

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

BUT, when I ran it in terminal, I can run it correctly.
I am trying to train a model to generate words embedding.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class emb( nn.Module ):

    def __init__( self ):
        super( emb, self ).__init__()
        self.embed_layer = nn.Embedding(8,3)

    def forward( self, inp ):
        out = self.embed_layer( inp )
        return out

embed_layer = emb()

inp = torch.tensor([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ])

out = embed_layer( inp )
print(out)
```

Comment: It's running perfectly in my jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please tell your pytorch version.